# Python, iterate through multiple lists in a dictionary object to find a specific value

Tags: python

Pulling data over a RESTapi, I'm left with a dictionary object containing multiple lists.  I'm looking for a very specific data point within one of the lists, however the actual amount of lists vary with each item in the dictionary.

I've tried to manually pull this field using indexing, etc..., but because the list is not always in the same place, I'm banging my head on the wall. The API results look something like this..

```
    b = [
    {'internal': False, 'protocol_parameters': [{'name': 'identifier', 'id': 1, 'value': 'x.x.x.x'}]},
      {'internal': False, 'protocol_parameters': [{'name': 'identifier', 'id': 0, 'value': 'y.y.y.y'}, {'name': 'incomingPayloadEncoding', 'id': 1, 'value': 'UTF-8'}]},
       {'internal': False, 'protocol_parameters': [{'name': 'incomingPayloadEncoding', 'id': 1, 'value': 'UTF-8'}, {'name': 'identifier', 'id': 0, 'value': 'z.z.z.z'}]}]

for a in b:
     c = (a['protocol_parameters'])[0].get('value')
     print(c)
```

This of course will not parse correctly because the list is not in a consistent place so I'm curious if I can parse all lists in the dictionary looking for a specific string. My end goal would be as shown below regardless of the list position.

```
x.x.x.x
y.y.y.y
z.z.z.z
```

In this example, find all lists that contain "identifier". Apologies if this is a noob mistake :) and thank you for your time.

Comment: The value shown for `b` results in a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Please [edit] your question and fix it.

Comment: what do you mean by *the list is not in a consistent place*? It seems that all lists are under the `"protocol_parameters"` key. Also your `b` expression is invalid... is it a dict, a list of dicts?

Comment: Your code isn't working as of now. Could you please fix it? The `b` variable is invalidly syntaxed

Comment: I apologize, this was my attempt at obfuscating the API results.  In this example, "B" is a list of dictionaries (protocol_parameters) and there are multiple lists inside each one. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you need to pick the `value` field from the item of `protocol_parameters` that contains name=identifier.

You may use `next()` to find the first item from the `protocol_parameters` list that matches that criteria. See below:

```
records = [{'internal': False, 'protocol_parameters': [{'name': 'identifier', 'id': 1, 'value': 'x.x.x.x'}]},
{'internal': False, 'protocol_parameters': [{'name': 'identifier', 'id': 0, 'value': 'y.y.y.y'}, {'name': 'incomingPayloadEncoding', 'id': 1, 'value': 'UTF-8'}]},
{'internal': False, 'protocol_parameters': [{'name': 'incomingPayloadEncoding', 'id': 1, 'value': 'UTF-8'}, {'name': 'identifier', 'id': 0, 'value': 'z.z.z.z'}]}
]

for record in records:
     identifier_param = next((prot_param for prot_param in record['protocol_parameters'] if prot_param['name']=='identifier'), None)
     if identifier_param:
         print(identifier_param['value'])
```

prints

```
x.x.x.x
y.y.y.y
z.z.z.z
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
b = [{'internal': False, 'protocol_parameters': [{'name': 'identifier', 'id': 1, 'value': 'x.x.x.x'}]},
{'internal': False, 'protocol_parameters': [{'name': 'identifier', 'id': 0, 'value': 'y.y.y.y'}, {'name': 'incomingPayloadEncoding', 'id': 1, 'value': 'UTF-8'}]},
{'internal': False, 'protocol_parameters': [{'name': 'incomingPayloadEncoding', 'id': 1, 'value': 'UTF-8'}, {'name': 'identifier', 'id': 0, 'value': 'z.z.z.z'}]}]

for a in b:
     c = next(param.get('value') for param in a['protocol_parameters'] if param.get('name')=="identifier")
     print(c)
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I was not familiar with the next function but thats really great.  Outputs as expected.